# How can I have odd number of plots with different widths in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have 7 plots that I would like to put them in one page with two columns and four rows.

I tried with both below codes to put them in one page. Since the plot number 4 is longer of the other ones I put it as the last plot. However, since I have specified two columns, the last plot has the same width as the first column plots. I tried to set different width for the last plot but it doesnt work. What do I need to change to correct it?

```
ggarrange(plts[[1]], plts[[2]], plts[[3]], plts[[7]], plts[[5]], plts[[6]], plts[[4]],
          heights = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 15), widths = c(11, 13, 11, 13, 11, 13, 25), 
          ncol = 2, nrow = 4)
```

and,

```
grid.arrange(
  grobs = plts,
  widths = c(11, 13),
  heights = c(5, 5, 5, 15, 5, 5, 5),
  layout_matrix = rbind(c(1, 2),
                        c(3, 7),
                        c(5,6),
                        c(4))
)
```

the below picture shows the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to other packages, perhaps the [patchwork package](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/) would suit your use case, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

ggplot_list <- list()
for (var in seq_along(mtcars)){
  ggplot_list[[var]] <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mtcars[[!!var]])) +
    geom_histogram()
}

layout <- "
ABCD
EFGG
"

ggplot_list[[1]] + ggplot_list[[2]] + ggplot_list[[3]] + ggplot_list[[4]] + ggplot_list[[5]] + ggplot_list[[6]] + ggplot_list[[7]] +
  plot_layout(design = layout)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: yes I could do the same thing in grid_arrange by putting the last one as c(4, NA). But it has another problem as it will make the last plot as wide as two columns. I want to give the last plot a custom width.

Comment: I don't understand; are you able to please edit your question to illustrate the problem and your desired outcome?